# Is Product of Loops homotopic to Loops Concatenation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

So I'm working on Viro's "Elementary Topology" textbook and I got stuck on this question:

Consider a loop $u : I \to X$ at $x_0$ , a loop $v : I \to Y$ at $y_0$ , and the loop
$w = u \times v : I \to X \times Y$ . We introduce the loops $u^′ : I \to X \times Y : t \mapsto (u(t), y _0 )$
and $v ′ : I \to X \times Y : t \mapsto (x_0 , v(t))$. Prove that $u^′ v^′ \sim w \sim v^′ u^′$ .

Where $f \sim g$ means $f$ homotopic to $g$. My thoughts on this are: I've proven earlier in Viro that $ f,g: X \to Y \times Z $ are homotopic iff $pr_L \circ f$ is homotopic to $ pr_L \circ g$, where $L \in \{Y,Z\}$. So it suffices to show that $ pr \circ u^′ v^′ \sim pr \circ w $. Easy to see that $ pr_X \circ w \equiv u $ and 
$$ 
pr_X \circ u^′ v^′ =  
\begin{cases}
u(2t): t \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \\ 
x_0 : t \in [\frac{1}{2},1]
\end{cases}
$$
Consider $\varphi: I \to I: t \mapsto \frac{t}{2}$. Then $pr_X \circ u^′ v^′ \circ \varphi \equiv u $. Since $\varphi \sim id$, then $ pr_X \circ u^′ v^′ \sim pr_X \circ w$. The same is for $pr_Y$ with $\varphi: t \mapsto \frac{t+1}{2}$. So $u^′ v^′ \sim w$. Analogously $v^′ u^′ \sim w$.

Is my proof correct? I'm not confident for that.

Comment: Do you have any _specific_ doubt about your proof?

Comment: Well, not really. The proof is actually easy but it took a lotta time for me lol

Comment: At first I was trying to prove it by drawing commutative diagram, using the fact that fundamental group of product is isomorphic to product of fundamental group and using quotient map from set of all loops to fundamental group. I'm still wondering if it's possible to prove it this way

Comment: The proof looks perfectly fine to me. Given that you know that two maps into a product are homotopic iff all their projections are homotopic, it is only left to show that $\text{pr}_X \circ u' v' = u \text{const}_{x_0} \sim u = \text{pr}_X \circ w$ and $\text{pr}_Y \circ v' u' = \text{const}_{y_0} v \sim v = \text{pr}_Y \circ w$. So the crucial part is knowing that $u \text{const}_{x_0} \sim u$ which is precisely what you have proven.

Comment: Very well then, thank you for provided comments and making me feel more confident for given proof :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in order to give this question an answer; the answer is yes. The proof is correct.